Generate all non-isomorphic caterpillar trees with $n$ vertices
A caterpillar or caterpillar tree is a tree in which all the vertices are within distance 1 of a central path.
From Wikipedia, I see that their count is also available in OEIS A005418. My question is, given $n$ vertices, is there a program to generate them? For example, I want to obtain all caterpillar graphs with 11 vertices.

Here is a SageMath code generating caterpillar graphs on $n$ nodes based on enriching a path graph with leaves. As an example it shows all such graphs on 6 nodes.

It's very much overkill to do canonical labelling to eliminate duplicates. if tuple(V) > tuple(reversed(V)): continue suffices.

@PeterTaylor: Indeed, thanks for the suggestion! I've updated the code, although for the case of $n=11$ with just $528$ graphs, it does not matter much.
